# Setting up a "Search Range" Feature in PHP?

Tags: php, search

I'm building a real-estate site where my visitors need to search based on "ranges."  For example, they need to search for rentals using the following preset price ranges:

600 - 800

800 - 1000

1000 - 1200

...

I've seen sites do this with two pull-downs: one for the "low" value, one for the "high" value.  Of course, putting values into the pull-downs is simple enough.  But is there a PHP script I could use to get all results that fall between the "low" and the "high" value?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean an sql query? You're using a database, right?

Comment: If this is SQL related, you might be looking for `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Galen: yes, sorry... I have a database of properties, with one field representing the price.

Comment: Galen: yes, sorry... I have a database of properties, with one field representing the price.

hakre: OK, BETWEEN seems hopeful!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suppose you have the prices in a Database Table.

So from the request you will get

```
$min = (int)$_GET['min'];
$max = (int)$_GET['max'];

$sql = "Selecy * from Properties where price>=$min and price<=$max";
```

and you can query this in mysql or whatever you are using.

Comment: Hi Phoenix.  Yes, my property listings are all in a database, with a field for price.  This seems like a good plan.  I'm going to be using CodeIgniter for this, and I think there's good Database class options for making this work.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Check out `range(  )` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php.

Comment: Thanks wescrow.  This definitely looks like a possibility.